# Problems running npm install on Elastic Beanstalck

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### Situation

I have a Laravel (5.4) application that uses npm, bower and gulp for frontend.

I have configured all with success on deploy but the `npm install` or `npm install --production` (that in my case is the same) command give me errors and makes the deploy to fail.

### Problem

Here is the "Causes" as response from AWS when i run `eb deploy` command.

```
Application update failed at 2017-06-07T17:08:38Z with exit status 1 and error: container_command 01-npm-install in .ebextensions/05-frontend-install.config failed.

npm WARN lifecycle npm is using /usr/bin/node but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /var/app/ondeck/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2017-06-07T17_08_38_740Z-debug.log.
Incorrect application version "app-5d9c-170607_190633" (deployment 40). Expected version "app-0466-170606_110037" (deployment 31).
```

The `.ebextensions/05-frontend-install.config` file has this content

```
container_commands:
  00-npm-upgrade:
    command: "npm install -g npm@latest"
  01-npm-install:
    command: "npm install --production"
  02-gulp-install:
    command: "sudo npm install gulp"
  03-bower-install:
    command: "sudo npm install bower"
  04-bower-deploy:
    command: "sudo bower install --allow-root"
  05-gulp-deploy:
    command: "sudo npm run prod"
```

Comment: Why do you need gulp and bower to run prod?

Comment: @SamH. `sudo npm run prod` is equal to `sudo gulp --production` in my `package.json` that minify all js and all css in 2 files for production. Some of assets are custom and some of assets are dependencies (even from bower)

Comment: I guess I mean, why don't you do this on a CI/CD server, and then `eb deploy`?

Comment: in my case i have the repo on gitlab and i make test-> deploy staging | deploy production (manual) so you suggest to make the css js operations in gitlab container build then zip all and deploy to staging/production at aws?
I did not considered it but i'll give it a try. Thx @SamH.

Comment: Uuuh... i am trying this but it's going to be tricky - i do not like this as solution

Comment: Are you deploying this on Beanstalk using the PHP app template, or one of the Docker ones?

Comment: Php app template. I did try docker without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Achived with an EB HOOK!

I solved my problem by using a **custom elastic beanstalk `post-deploy` [platform hook](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html#custom-platform-hooks)** (sounds great eh?)

my `04-nodenpm.config` file has this content:

```
container_commands:
  00-entersudoi:
    command: "sudo -i"
  01-removeoldnode:
    command: " yum remove -y nodejs npm"
  02-get-noderpm:
    command: " curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -"
  03-ensurecggmake:
    command: " yum install -y gcc-c++ make"
  04-installnodenpm:
    command: " yum install -y nodejs"
  05-exitsudoi:
    command: "exit"

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99npminstall.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      cd /var/app/current/
      sudo npm install -g gulp bower laravel-elixir
      sudo bower install --allow-root
      sudo gulp --production
```

The part that solved the problem is under `files:` where i am manually adding an `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99npminstall.sh` file with `content:` that **as a post deploy action** makes the `npm install ...` and all the stuff i wanted.

## TL;DR:

npm seems not be totally available on container_commands. Use a post deploy hook to fire those npm installation commands.

Refs & Usefull links:

http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/29-aws-elasticbeanstalk-deployment-hooks
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137136

Comment: This was exactly what I needed for Laravel mix `npm run prod`. Weird that so few people seem to encounter this problem. I guess everyone just commits their compiled assets. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @wimbrace few years from this answer and I figured out that build assets in production is not a best practice. I now build assets in my ci after tests... Then I deploy.