# Laravel Elastic Beanstalk, cannot install-run npm?

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-linux

I have my Elastic Beanstalk with Laravel 5.4 here's my 02-node.config:

```
commands:
  01-install-node:
    command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | s$
    command: "sudo yum -y install nodejs"
```

And 03-deploy.config

```
container_commands:
  01-laravel-deploy:
    command: "php artisan migrate"
    command: "php artisan config:clear"
    command: "php artisan config:cache"
    command: "php artisan route:clear"
    command: "php artisan route:cache"
    command: "npm install"
    command: "npm run prod"
```

During deployment I get:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-018d9dd563f6ba0e6] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ar/app/ondeck
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/app/ondeck/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0.
container_command 01-laravel-deploy in .ebextensions/03-deploy.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-018d9dd563f6ba0e6'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | s$
```

doesn't make any sense. The double-quoting isn't closed, and you're redirecting it to `s$`, but you should redirect to `bash` instead, so:

```
command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -E -"
```

For more details about the error, check: `npm-debug.log` and `eb-activity.log` as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because npm does not have permission to do the npm install. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419064/problems-running-npm-install-on-elastic-beanstalck) for the correct solution.